# Android Volley posting several rows of data to mysql

Tags: android, android-volley

i am posting over 100 rows of data from android to mysql, but only the last row is inserted, this is my code

```
 public void insert() {
    String url = "http://myurl";
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("item_name", "Droider");
    params.put("item_name", "chuyu");
    params.put("item_name", "solo");
    params.put("item_name", "shaq");



    CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError response) {
            Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());
        }
    });
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
```

i thought of jsonarrayrequest but most examples also post a single row, is this possible with volley?? please help thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your server side app is mostly overwriting the values. 
Instead of calling your param `item_name` name it `item_name[]` and in your server side code treat it like an array.